# Hidden trails and how to recognise them

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, published-adventures

I am relatively new to D&D but am attempting to DM in a couple of days' time. I am introducing friends (also new to D&D) with the adventure *Lost Mine of Phandelver*.

> During the "Goblin Trail" section there is "a trail hidden behind thickets on the north side of the road leading northwest. A character who succeeds on a DC 10 Wisdom (Survival) check recognizes..."

As far as I am aware a DC 10 Wisdom (survival) check entails a character to roll a 1d20 and add their Wisdom (survival) modifier to the outcome.

So my question is:
Do I ask all characters to make a Wisdom (survival) check when they are approaching the hidden trail or do I wait until a player asks to investigate further and then ask them to make the check?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se, LMOP. This is actually a good question for this site. Make sure you check out our [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), because it borders closely on something we like to avoid which is entirely opinion based questions. I did edit your title to more closely match the question's body, I hope you don't mind. If what I did wasn't correct, there should be a rollback or reedit option for you to correct it.

Comment: When you see an answer you feel fully resolves your issue, and is the best provided, make sure to click the Check (and possibly up arrow) to let people know that's what you liked best. For this type of question that relies on [subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) answers, I recommend seeing if 2 or 3 come in before selecting your favorite. But feel free to upvote any you like.

Answer (score 11):

## You wait until a player asks to investigate further and then ask them to make the check.

That's how it works in D&D. You describe the environment, players describe their actions, you request rolls (when necessary).

In your case, if they find the trail, you describe that players see some footsteps, some marks on the mud. If they ask to follow the trail or try and interpret the footsteps, you request the Survival check. When they succeed, the players

> recognize that about a dozen goblins have come and gone along the trail, as well as signs of two human-sized bodies being hauled away from the ambush site.

Consider that, if the characters didn't care about the trail, why would they know how many goblins would have walked there (or not)? It takes time to interpret such things, and it is the characters that need to decide to do it. If they're in a hurry, or are just reckless, they don't have access to that information.

Comment: "Some footsteps coming from some place and heading somewhere" sounds like a huge clue for "a hidden trail leading northwest", doesn't it.

Comment: Im not familiar with the adventure, so some re wording may be necessary :p

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, games go more smoothly and quickly if you don't have *players* telling you when to stop for die rolls. Some skills, such as Perception and Investigation, are inevitable. It's normal for players to want to look into things.

However, setting the precedent that they need to *ask* to make their own skill rolls for everything can be a real immersion breaker. Besides, what is the likeliness of a player suddenly wanting to make a Survival check in the exact scene it's necessary?

My solution is to make a precedent of the GM asking for the roll, but in this case I might ask for it as soon as they enter the woods. I would indicate it was for them to follow the sometimes questionable trail, or something similar. That way, if they roll poorly or highly, nobody is *immediately* hounding you for results. But lo and behold, anyone rolling above a 10 notices this hidden trail partway through the path...

Of course it's up to you what seems preferable, but I've had good results from asking the party to make their checks as soon as they enter the zone/forest/room/etc so if they fail, I simply don't mention that secret path/door/chest unless they then decide to request a reroll. In such a case, I would only allow the reroll *if their character had reason to reassess the situation*, not just because they rolled a 2.

Answer (score 1):

In 5e, each player's passive perception is equal to their perception bonus plus 10, as we all know. However, when it comes to natural ability to spot things, the DM should have each player's Passive Perception behind the screen so that they know, because isn't it blatantly obvious something is there if the DM asks everyone for their passive perceptions? If someone doesn't have high enough, they will probably immediately ask to roll for it. This would be my solution. And also, I think I got this from Matthew Mercer on his DM series.
As for the Passive scores for other abilities, I'm not sure... But with that being said, it wouldn't hurt for the DM to have copies of each player's character. Perhaps pictures on their phone. That way they will always have it and also be able to plan their adventures around character backgrounds or personality traits.

Comment: DC10 challenge is not a good candidate for a passive check, when it is enough that just one party member notices it. No point considering it a challenge at all, just description fluff for that particular path.

Answer (score 0):

### This sounds like a good opportunity for a 'passive check'.

Passive checks are calculated by: 10 + check modifier.

> The adventure works much better if the characters find the trail immediately after defeating the goblins. This is why the DC is set so low that almost any character will be able to achieve it.

In this case, passive perception, a passive check important enough to get its own box on the character sheet, would be appropriate. It represents a character's general awareness, when not actively looking out for anything in particular, but rather being generally on guard. When you use a passive check, you simply take the number calculated, instead of rolling.

> After they defeat the goblins, you essentially have two choices. You can either wait for your players to investigate the area (which they may not do, in which case do not prompt them, as this would be a failure of player agency), at which point you ask for a perception check, or you can simply declare that, since one of the characters has a passive perception greater than 10 (which they will), they automatically find the trail.

The character to make a rolled perception check, assuming that all the characters are doing the investigating, should be the one with the highest perception modifier. You may consider giving them advantage for being assisted by the other party members.

In the case of a passive check, simply use the highest passive perception.